# can't get knockout object property value

Tags: knockout.js

When I try to get the value of foo.Id in the click event (removeAFoo -> removeFoo) in the  I get function text 'function b(){if(0...'. What needs to change to get the property value of foo.Id? Another weird thing is when I call indexOf() on viewModel.foos array it returns the index even though that array says it's zero length.

```
function getFoos() {
    viewModel.foos([]);
    var data = [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Joe' },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Jon' },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Name: 'Jim' }        
    ]

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var f = new foo();
        f.Id(data[i].Id);
        f.Name(data[i].Name);

        viewModel.foos.push(f);
    }
};

var viewModel = {
    foos: ko.observableArray([]),

    reloadFoos: function() {
        getFoos();
    },

    removeAFoo: function(foo) {
        removeFoo(foo);
    }
};

var foo = function() {
    this.Id = ko.observable();
    this.Name = ko.observable();
};

function removeFoo(foo) {
    alert(viewModel.foos.indexOf(foo));
    alert(foo.Id);
    viewModel.foos.splice(viewModel.foos.indexOf(foo), 1);
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

getFoos();
​

<div data-bind="foreach: foos">
    <div style="float: left">
        <button data-bind="click : $parent.removeAFoo, attr: { id: Id }">
        </button>
        <label data-bind="text: Name">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suedeuno/gAUgV/12/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the value of foo.id you need to remember to use parentheses:

like so:

document.write(foo.Id());

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that.

Comment: 4 days playing with Knockout.js and I just realised that parentheseis is needed!